# Android Device Manager system image download error, Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

Made an empty Xamarin forms project with shell through visual studio, tried debugging but sometime after the download starts this error pops up saying:

"System image download error. The decryption operation failed, see inner exception."

I've looked at older threads about the topic but none of the solutions seem to work for me.
I've tried enabling Hyper-V, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: In VS, select menu Tools > Android > Android Device Manager. Start one of those devices. Same symptom, or different?  Click "+ New" above the list of devices - make a new one. Start it. Work any better?

Comment: Does this occure on your code or your device? Have you tested the code on other PC? Does the emulator work well? If no, try to check the real device about it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve doesn't help

Comment: When you manually start a device, is the device able to start okay? If you don't send xamarin project to device, does it get error on its own, or does it seem to be okay? Can you launch any built-in app? I want to know if it is the emulator image itself that is having trouble, or the attempt to download from VS. Also, that error that pops up - is there a "copy details" or "copy to clipboard" button?  If so, and you paste it into your question, does it show any more detail (like what that "inner exception" is)?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes, it gets the error without the project too. and i can't run the emulator at all, nor does it show what the error is. all it says is that the decryption operation failed. there isn't a details or copying button either.

Comment: 1) Try Tools > Android  > Android SDK Manager > "Tools" tab: if any updates, install them. 2)  To see if simplest case of previous android version works: Tools > Android > Android Device Manager > "+ Add": Base Device = Pixel 2 XL, Processor: x86, OS: Pie 9.0 - API 28. Create. Start.

Comment: 3) In Windows Features, also select "Windows Hypervisor Platform". Reboot PC. 4) If still doesn't work, UNINSTALL Visual Studio. Reboot to be sure everything is clean. Install again, selecting the feature that includes Xamarin (this also includes up-to-date Android).